# reselect selector always returns a new reference to array

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, immutable.js, reselect

I'm adding a new feature to a project and since I'm writing the reducer from scratch I decided to finally give normalized state, reselect and immutablejs a go.
However, my selector keeps returning a new reference to the same array whenever I change one of it's properties, for example, changing the "siteId" property on one of the cards which is triggered by the "SCHEDULE_DOCTOR_AGENDA_CHANGE_CARD_SITE" action.

Here's a codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/reactredux-3sulk?fontsize=14

Below is the state:

```
{
  cards: {
    byId: {
      xtNRPmeZh: {
        cardId: "xtNRPmeZh",
        actId: "0000000540",
        specialityDesc: "MEDICINA GERAL E FAMILIAR",
        staffDesc: "Abel Garcia Abejas",
        staffKey: "abel|abejas|41631",
        siteId: "0000000015",
        siteExternalCode: "HCD",
        siteExternalId: "1",
        siteList: ["wto3vb3cSp", "jBZznWcTm3"],
        procedureGroupTypeConsult: true,
        mainSchedulingId: "FYV8gCC7-"
      },
      XduPAjiL8: {
        cardId: "XduPAjiL8",
        actId: "0000000543",
        specialityDesc: "Cardiologia",
        staffDesc: "Duarte Nuno Cacela",
        staffKey: "duarte|cacela|32938",
        siteId: "0000000010",
        siteExternalCode: "HCD",
        siteExternalId: "1",
        siteList: ["jYyr402brR", "mfp69ivQWg"],
        procedureGroupTypeConsult: true,
        mainSchedulingId: "-M5ghgxzn"
      }
    },
    allCardIds: ["XduPAjiL8", "xtNRPmeZh"]
  },
  siteLists: {
    byId: {
      wto3vb3cSp: {
        value: "0000000015",
        externalCode: "HCD",
        externalId: "1",
        label: "CUF Descobertas Hospital"
      },
      jBZznWcTm3: {
        value: "0000000005",
        externalCode: "HCIS",
        externalId: "2",
        label: "CUF Infante Santo Hospital"
      },
      jYyr402brR: {
        value: "0000000015",
        externalCode: "HCD",
        externalId: "1",
        label: "CUF Descobertas Hospital"
      },
      mfp69ivQWg: {
        value: "0000000010",
        externalCode: "CCSDR",
        externalId: "10",
        label: "CUF S. Domingos Rana Clínica"
      }
    },
    allSiteResultIds: ["wto3vb3cSp", "jBZznWcTm3", "jYyr402brR", "mfp69ivQWg"]
  },
  currentCard: "XduPAjiL8"
}
```

The action:

```
export const changeDoctorAgendaCardSite = (cardId, siteId) => dispatch => {
  dispatch({
    type: "SCHEDULE_DOCTOR_AGENDA_CHANGE_CARD_SITE",
    cardId,
    siteId
  });
};
```

The reducer:

```
const doctorAgendaReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SCHEDULE_DOCTOR_AGENDA_ADD_CARD": {
      return state
        .mergeIn(["cards", "byId"], action.doctorAgendaCard)
        .setIn(["cards", "allCardIds"], action.newAllCardIds)
        .mergeIn(["siteLists", "byId"], action.newSiteLists)
        .setIn(["siteLists", "allSiteResultIds"], action.newAllSiteListsIds)
        .setIn(["currentCard"], action.cardId);
    }
    case "SCHEDULE_DOCTOR_AGENDA_CHANGE_CARD_SITE": {
      return state.setIn(
        ["cards", "byId", action.cardId, "siteId"],
        action.siteId
      );
    }
    case "SCHEDULE_DOCTOR_AGENDA_CHANGE_CURRENT_CARD":
      return state.setIn(["currentCard"], action.cardId);

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

I've been reading and comparing code online for hours and cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong, any help would be appreciated.

edit: is the following selector the issue?

```
import { createSelector } from "reselect";
import getDoctorAgendaCard from "./getDoctorAgendaCard";
import getDoctorAgendaSiteArray from "./getDoctorAgendaSiteArray";
import getDoctorAgendaSiteListsById from "./getDoctorAgendaSiteListsById";

const getDoctorAgendaTargetCard = createSelector(
  [getDoctorAgendaCard, getDoctorAgendaSiteArray, getDoctorAgendaSiteListsById],
  (card, siteArray, siteListsById) => ({
    ...card,
    options: siteArray.map(item => siteListsById[item])
  })
);

export default getDoctorAgendaTargetCard;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly reselect is returning a new list when your action updates the store because you updated it with immutablejs which returns a new list. This has a new reference so now your reselect selector will perform its work again.

Comment: do you mean this selector?

```
const getDoctorAgendaTargetCard = createSelector(
  [getDoctorAgendaCard, getDoctorAgendaSiteArray, getDoctorAgendaSiteListsById],
  (card, siteArray, siteListsById) => ({
    ...card,
    // options: teste(siteArray, siteListsById),
    options: siteArray.map(item => siteListsById[item])
  })
);
 ```

Comment: I don't know if you have an issue at all. The issue you are describing is how reselect should work if you are always making immutable updates. If you are making immutable changes it means you completely replace the value, object, or list with a new updated one. Reselect just memoizes the parameters that were passed in the last time that selector was called and shallowly compares them to the new parameters. If they are different, and if your immutably updating they will be, then it will rerun the selector. If it's not different it will just return the result of the last run.